# Simulate sedimentation of solids in fluid

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want to animate the sedimentation of two different (opaque) fractions from a (transparent) liquid. What is the best way to go about this?

I want an end result that looks somewhat like [centrifuged blood](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/3-s2.0-B9780123813732000685-f00068-19-9780123813732.jpg).

[image]

[The process should look something like what is happening in the third cylinder from the left](https://youtu.be/wfYQEYTaAMo?t=100), only that whatever settles isn't poured in, but that the liquid instead starts out with a uniform color.

Video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfYQEYTaAMo&t=100s) (third tube)

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you have a video reference of the kind of animation you are talking about?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @moonboots What I'm thinking of is something like [this](https://youtu.be/wfYQEYTaAMo?t=100), specifically what can be seen in the third column from the left, only that the liquid starts out at a uniform color.

Comment: so you need to see the powder pouring into the liquid?

Comment: @moonboots No, that's the part I don't need. The liquid starts out with the powder evenly mixed in.

Comment: maybe a reverse smoke simulation?

Comment: @moonboots After having a look at it, yeah, that sounds like a good solution. Then I only need a translucent object to get the effect of the particles settling out of a liquid. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @moonboots After some fiddling around I have determined that smoke simulations could work, and while the end result may loom better, I have found another way: Just make a material where the properties like Alpha and some other things depend on the texture coordinates. I will be posting a solution here after I am done so that someone else maybe can use it.

Comment: Yes I've tried with some Noise Texture, not easy though

Comment: I don't actually want a lot of noise, since what is settling out is red blood cells, which are of course really small, and so they create a uniform gradient. The secret ingredient is a texture coordinate node, and some math I don't even understand myself any more. As soon as I have figured out what I have cobbled together there (because of course it's flipped the wrong way and I need to make documentation so that doesn't happen again), I'll post what I have done here.